# Information graphical visualization for web-page: Is there any better way instead of small PNG files?

Tags: html, image, visualization

Let's describe the task first:

I'd like to create a web-page with several rows of a text and a small (let's say 100 by 20 pixels) graphic for each one. Each graphic generated dynamically (so it will be a new one each time the page is loaded).

The only way I can imagine to my self is to create on server a new PNG file each time the row is indicated and include the link to this newly created file to HTML: `<img src='row1graph.png'>`.

If the page would be the single image - I could output it directly to the browser, but this is not my case.

So the question is: is there any better way to handle such images and skip unnecessary disk access operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to optimize small graphics in a web page. You can use the tile-set concept (all the graphics in a single image, with offsets based on e.g. background-position), or you can embed the PNG directly into the page as base-64:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,yourbase64image" />
```

The options have different merits based on file size and browser support. And of course, both can be combined - you can have an embedded tile-set.

Comment: Thank you for your input! First approach is also required to write a file on disk, but actually it is interesting for some cases. In my particular case I'd stick with the second one - this is right for me! It looks like it is widely supported: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support

Answer (score 2):

You can serve an image from PHP rather than from a file - I mean you can have PHP dynamically create an image and serve it rather than having to have a file in your webserver's filesystem and having to refer to it by name in the src field of an  tag in your HTML.

So, instead of

```
<image src="xyz.png" alt="..." size="...">
```

you can use

```
<img src="/php/thumb.php?param1=128&param2=45"/>
```

which causes the PHP script at `/php/thumb.php` to be called when the page is rendered. In that script, you can dynamically create the image (using extra parameters if you wish) like this:

```
<?php    
header("Content-type: image/png");
$p1 = $_GET['param1'];
$p2 = $_GET['param2'];

// Create a 200x200 image
$im    = imagecreatetruecolor(200,200);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$red   = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

// Here you can draw in the image, write on it, set any pixels, calculate any colours you wish

// Draw a white rectangle, then a red one
imagefilledrectangle($im, 50, 50, 100, 100, $white);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 75, 75, 150, 150, $red);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I have omitted some code after the first 3 lines so you just see the technique rather than all the gory details of my code. The actual lines you are interested in are:

```
header(...image/png);
```

which tells the browser what type of stuff is coming - i.e. an image, and

```
imagepng();
```

which actually sends the stream of PNG data to the browser.

The code above produces this in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and a huge effort! However in my case data URI scheme will be better solution as it allows to insert the image creation code into the main page generation script.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to avoid "unnecessary disk access" and since the image size is small you can use [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). You can store the encoded strings in the database as well.

This way `<img src='row1graph.png'>` becomes...

```html
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA8Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2ODApLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gMTAwCv/bAEMAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf/bAEMBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf/AABEIABQAZAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAAAAX0BAgMABBEFEiExQQYTUWEHInEUMoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzYnKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/xAAfAQADAQEBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqCg4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2dri4+Tl5ufo6ery8/T19vf4+fr/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APzs8TfBbx+tviP4uaP4LSCaGe71Jb3TtTRbSJ0mnUrqUlzEYWiR1lc/Oi7jkYzXvc/jP4EaPpEup6z4z+F0NhpmoPoeqa7qV/4Z0vTZtb0+2tpNQslur+aG1nu4VureS5htZJDBLKYXCypJGn5ueN/jP4d0nwf4qu9D8a+D/EmvQaFfR6H4ai8TWVxda9rM8MkOnaUsFtfvcXC3l3LBBNHBGW8h5cMMAH89PDz+M9cvjpvjjw34QisYr6TV9H8H+J9RuPh5ZBdYmn1PUNJsdTOqeHtJ1gW+rz3TPYaz4m0h9bgmtE0DWLeW41vQrnxcw4MpYmVOhPP8wxWJtKdKlXlhpVHTUX7RUo0KNOUnUnGEU7yUWknC0019PgOMp4ONSrSyTA4bDy5YVKtL2/s1V5o+zdWdWpOEFThKpKSSi5R2kuWz/fiL9pD9ji11CNYviv8ACa01KCRGguE1Xw/GkUuPkeO92pBHjdlZFnC4YfNzXsB8TeDfGttpE/hLxloevRmYvFNoN9o2txyxsgYlRY3k33gQVxjHU1+WHgn9onx18PNMh0gfBL9lrwVa2lvGsMvxN0Lw4lvawMo8qR4dV+PNpPbAg5WRobwAnP2eb7ho6r8f/EHjvW/Dskus6Deano2pQy6d4e+A/hDU9e0m1sJ7yGbVbLw1qXhvw78MPhXp6am1vameT4gaj44u47mGC6svEWnGzt7g/IVuDsBVp1YYrE4jDuk7RnJUseo1ITh7tSny4b2cUr80nWfI1Zp6s+ohxdjYypSoYXDYlVLOUEqmBvCUF71Oo54l1ZJtKMVSTldWa1v+6/8AwTs0Sz/4fR/saW+q7L2KX4PftKzD7VELZRPb/D+9ntMiMtkx3FvHIrMSNygNlBX27/wXf/a9+Ov7M/7XXw98BfB/48eJfgn8OPEH7LOg+KL7SPBXhfwVqw1j4hTfHPXtBuJzc+IPA3i+70271LwzYWmjG+jit7G0WGyeVJg0ttc/nj/wSag17Tf+Cy37CKatpN9oGleKfgd+1Jr/AIW0HVfHGo/EPVdI0KX4V3r2drceJdQhZnk89L6SfTLLUdf0vSJW+w6brd3aQxiL6I/4OW9c8JaR+3J+zxc+Pby3tNAuf2YNHstb+zXd7Hri6Q3xp8eXEz6La2Vrd3F1e3H2UxwNcfYLWFkmuo9Ts7u0gmX73JMH7PLMHhot+5haK504RkkqkHo4urCLjeScoOrFauHOmub4zMMXTln2KxVWnSnTlVxEvY4iNSdCVSWFqRhzwcsNOUHP2ckpewk2oqbpON4/k7+1f/wVR/bS+FOm+Fbr4U/t5eMdVu9R+2w6jo/jXwd8G9LuzbpNbLZ6vb3/AIn+GfhKGW2eK7s7VrWysb2WRYZr6RbK3sr0QT/sofGDV/8Agrp4w+HHwD/ab13Q/FX7RF3rsZ1DxNY33w8Wf4k/Dzw5/adxaeIYbfwldWtlo/jX4f6X9vjktxptpB4k8MWtm1uZbhwJvzl/bD+Ong6Z7Gw+EEN/ceHW0yKK8e8jMWpTXUPyG01Ox13QdUgutOkBjJht9Smjvkju4da+2QzwRx43/BOz48L8LP2+vgf8Y47XR/DmkfD3XPBn9pNovhvw/wCF4ofDGqeJPC3h/wAXrcR+H9M0xb1W8O6tq6q99FJOkLmJDEh8tbr5I8xwdPD4p1oyw1aOMoV41ovFRrUm5wvONKNPW8qM04yU6cpJNu0362U8UV+F82xeLweGy72GY4avlOPwNWg6uBrZfmLh7anGDqe2jHD1adLE4X9/7WlOjRjVnUtNS/Qf9oD/AIIt/tZfsQ+OvG3iHR/CeofFP4TXw1fTtF8YeC7aa/1TRJLlRLp+t3+hW/nX8W2CNoZ50hlgtbiV3EnlgNX4ofEr9lv4tat4S174iDTNX1HSdP1u6025nS1mPl3cBHnrcPsCRyBiC6S7ZCw+YEqa/wBgLSodM8WaTZajGba+sb+yiuIJR5dxb3FvPCHjkXIaOSKRGDqwyGRgQSDX4p/tj/BT4QeAfDPxS0nTfBGj6c/jnWZPEGq2kVnbJp9/qU1sIbi/ht/L8uC4mCA3HlInmSkyMDJIzH5zN8xxGWYdVIzUoQqL43rKOl4O28mkkpKz6O92z6DIsnwGe4ypg6sJ0ZOjJxVL3oRqNxXPFSd4wjrJw5ppt2XKrI/y9vDnwY8ceJ5NVj03Rby5On28s12hBz8uT5YHV5Nw+VQM5z0r6S/ZZ/Zz0rX7fxN418ZQ/aU8H6d4jvZtHuHMCRS6Jpt1estxLn93IptiqlhhHcHBAIP9BviD4N+EdP1DWZdE0TT9Nmld9klrbrF5mGb93IVUA7egLdPevlCX9lH4s+M/CHxm8O/s/wDhK78S+MPiFod/otloOnXWm6axvL947XXrz7Zq15p+n26x6HLqF3ma7iaRo/LiEkjhDwZVxBUznHUsvjTlGFarhU40pS9tOl7WnGvTjKHvKU4SlyuHvJ7aq5pnXCdDhrBVc2qVqdX6nQxlVzrxj9XpVKdGVTD1qkZ3i4QnCLnGpzQd7vS5o/s3f8FSPEl98Dvh54S8S6HBo/8Awq3S7/wDoCeFraKwtLrwyNe1fxlpMt9AiKj6nZDxjPok15t87UbbSbTUL15b+6uppCui+E3/AAS0/bD8DeCbC2uv2c4LzV9cu9U1/WbBfFfgSO38O3EmoXGk6ZoNo114uZ54Lfw3pGh3rzJNcqbm/uI3uJLiObBX7nhqePo4ehSi+SNOnCEYewqe7CKgoJ2jpaKjdbq0k9UfgFbM8mxNariK2OwtStXqTq1ZyxlHmnVqS56kn+9V3Kbbbsk73Sszk/DPwb+E0bJqtj8N/BWk6hapaz213pXhzS7K4gkuIZPMaKeK286PgFQVkB2swJYE1ua5oGkvC1pLY29xasozBcQwzRYIUlSjxlSvswPSiiv5udSpUqOVSc5tXs5ylJqz0s5NtW6WP6AhTp06aVOEIJ8t1CMYp3gr3UUk79b7nkWtfDHwXrn2G1udHjtDYzKum3Okyy6Rd6Y075lexm05rfyt7O7SRsskE2+QTxSrJIrfPXjv40+MPhl8U7/4a2Vr4X8RaVoHjvw7oNjrHiDw1plr4hk0q+HiSB7e/uvCEXhTT9QliXR7F4r670yXUGljke4up/PmDlFfV5P/ALVSrxxP+0Rp0moRr/vlBLD1pJQVTmUUpRjJJWtJJrVI+Zzf/Zq+HeH/ANndSpF1HR/dObdahFubp8rk3FuLcr3Ta2P6D/8AgkV4i8R6r/wVy/4Jk22ta7f6zbab+zd+1dZaNb362ezRdJi+GPiO8g0fT2tbS1lGn29zeXc0Ru5Lu9LXMokvJF2BPQf+DroK/wC2Z+z5KUUN/wAMnaPgDJChfi58V8AFizY65yxJJJJyaKK+8wGsqDereEopt6tpQoJJ36JaLstD4jENuVS7v+8qP5+2nr+LP5KPHdxLPpsTsxVp4LAMUJVlW5igmlEbElkyXMakHcseADu+asH9nAmf4pzwytJJHLDpkUokllkMiS+L/C6yBzLI5bcCQSSTiiivUhv93/pSMsc24q7b+Dd36M/uf+En7f8A+0d8K/8AgkN+zX418Ka/ow8ZXNzL8NG8UatpMur6snh/wzbfYtKnVry/e0l1aO0tobea9urW4SVE3m3ExaU/hj+2f+2H+1b4z0uDxnr37QPxEnv5ZbZG06CfQbTRAssyK4XT7fQkIGGOB5+OmQcUUV46weExGGxXt8Lh63LiKij7ahSqcqVRWS54ysl0se7Wx2NwtbDSwuMxWGlPCUnKVDEVqLk3TjdydOcXJvq3e5+fkfjz4m/FHWrDS/FfxQ8cyWNwLdriDS9RsdIM33XYPNYaZDOPMJw5WVWI4DDrWRof7QHxi/Z/+K2oWXwl8f8AiTwm4RYzfQ6re39463ERScyf2pPe2srSozK5ktW+ViBjNFFXhsNhsPClPD4ehQnTqR5JUaVOlKFo3XJKEYuNnqrNWep5+MxeKxcqsMVicRiYVYzjVhiK1StGrGSSlGpGpKSnGS0kpJprRo/pM/ZQ/bX+PfjT4M6HrXi3XdF8Qaybu7tJdUvvD9hHd3EVtHbCMz/YRaQPJlnZ5BCrOzEk4wAUUV9/QnOVGk5Sk24Rbbk222tW23dt92fkmKweEjia8Y4XDRjGrNJRoUkklJ2SSjZJWVktrLsf/9k="/>
```