# Can ImageMagick resize images server-side before it's served to the client?

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, responsive-design, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to optimize for page speed & bandwidth. If the image A on my server is 1000 X 1000, I don't want that to be served to a mobile device when an image B (scaled down of A) 100 X 100 might suffice just fine. But rather than store both image A & B on my server, I'd like to just have image A and have image B created "on demand" and served.

Therefore, is there a way to use ImageMagick to create a resized image, store it, and serve it on-demand all at once? In other words, the code (using `RMagick gem`) I'm thinking about is the below, but I'm stuck in the sense that the `img.resize` function would return a new image, but not necessarily have it stored in that path that I'm immediately able to use.

```
/* css.scss.erb file for background images */
@media ... {
  background-image: url(<%= image-path "#{img.resize_to_fit(100 [, 100])"} %>)
}

<!-- html.erb file for regular images -->
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
  <%= image_tag "#{img.resize_to_fit(100 [, 100])" %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 visible-md">
  <%= image_tag "#{img.resize_to_fit(700 [, 700])" %>
</div>
```

How can I use ImageMagick for this?

Comment: Have a look at, and maybe vote for :-) my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062426/information-graphical-visualization-for-web-page-is-there-any-better-way-instea/28063422#28063422

Comment: @MarkSetchell does that work for Rails?