# Magick++ to display an image with CGI

Tags: c++, imagemagick, cgi, jpeg, magick++

I recently began using Magick++ (C++ API for ImageMagick) with the goal of creating a website that could display randomly generated images. I am trying to write a CGI script which would create a JPEG Image, set the color of its pixels, and then return the image information as `Content-type: image/jpg`.

Reading through the documentation, I only find functions for writing image files to disk. I do not see one which would do what I am hoping to do, along the lines of `std::cout << Image` or `std::cout << Blob`

My goal is to be able to display the image generated by the script in a webpage, without needing to write the image to disk.

I know that PerlMagick has a display function which does what I am trying to do - I am wondering if I can do the same with Magick++.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think, while possible, C++ is a bit awkward as a CGI and most people would go for Perl or PHP nowadays. Have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062426/information-graphical-visualization-for-web-page-is-there-any-better-way-instea/28063422#28063422

Comment: This may help http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/coe518/LinuxJournal/elj2005-132-CforCGI.pdf

Comment: I've been working with multiprecision integers, so perl is much too slow and inefficient. I've created a random-text generating website using entirely c++-based cgi (cgicc) and it's working quite well. So I'm hoping I can continue using it for this image project.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misjudged your level of experience.

Comment: No worries - I'm definitely a noob when it comes to working with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for blobs - *Binary Large Objects*. Basically, you create an image of type `Image` and a blob of type `Blob`. You populate your image either by reading from a file or generating your random data, then you write your image to the blob (to encode it) and you can then write that to the user's browser.

Please excuse my useless C/C++ skills...

```
Image  image;
Blob   blob;

// set type to JPEG
image.magick("JPEG");   

// generate/read/fill image here
image.read("image.jpg");

// encode image as JPEG
image.write(&blob);   

// now send MIME type to browser
std::cout << "Content-type: image/jpeg" << CRLF;

// ... followed by blob
write(1,(char*)blob.data(),blob.length());
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark - I'm wondering still about the send-blob-to-browser step - is that as simple as `std::cout << blob`? or is there a different function required?

Comment: I've never seen it done... there is a `const void *data()` and `size_t length()` defined inside Blob, so I guess you would get those and pass them to `write()` but am not at my computer to check.

Comment: It looks like my guess was about right, see example here by `spongemonkey` ... http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24984

Comment: this is also code for writing to a file - im trying to modify it to work with an ostringstream, but im not sure how to translate the line `outFile.write((char*)blob.data(),blob.length());`

Comment: It should just be `stdout`, i.e. file descriptor 1 as I have it.

Comment: I get a 500 error when I include that line - i think this will only work if the blob data can be written to an ostringstream

Comment: This seems to be working now: `streampunk.write((char*)bablob.data(),bablob.length());


std::cout << "Content-type: image/jpg\n\n";
std::cout << streampunk.str();` - I still haven't been able to pipe that information into the source of an img element, but ill ask another question if i cant figure that out. thank you!

Comment: Try running this in your Terminal... `convert -size 640x416 xc:gray +noise random result.jpg`   :-)